# What should we do with answers copied from other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, answers

Recently I asked a question and one of the [most voted answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/1468/72) is totally plagiarized from an answer to a similar question in [Robotics StackExchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/are-artificial-intelligence-and-robotics-different/2267#2267)

I think it is against the site policy as the answer is being copied here without any any attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you point out, it is a copy-paste without attribution, which is a [violation of the Stack Exchange rules](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/licensing).

So it should be flagged, using a custom moderator flag to explain the situation.

I have raised that flag.

Comment: I have already flagged it.

Comment: @VishnuJK Good! That's all we need to do. I flagged it  after I saw your comment yesterday. It may take a while before the flag gets handled, because currently our only moderators are SE employees. This will get better after we have some more moderators (during/after public beta).